# How to make first pair of fields REQUIRED and others not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am using Ajax to submit forms in serial.  I am trying to make the first s_referee_email + s_referee_fname pair required while the second or others not - there will be up to five of these pairs.  I cant seem to figure how to make just the first pair required without breaking the form.  I have tried using HTML5 and some answers from stack but havent been able to get anything to work.  Any advice is greatly appreciated!

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/badsmell/gcrvqbna/

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--serial submit ajax-->
  <script>
     function mySubmit(){
     var myForms = $("form");
     myForms.each(function(index) {
     var form = myForms.eq(index);
     var serializedForm = form.serialize();
     serializedForm += '&s_referer_fname='+$('#s_refererFname').val();
     $.post("http://post.aspx", serializedForm, function (data, status) {
     if (status === "success"){
     window.location.href= "http://redirect";
     }  
     });   
     });
     }
  </script>
  <title>Forward a copy to a friend</title>
  <style type="text/css">
     *[class=hide] {
     display: none
     }      
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <!--hidden iframe-->
  <iframe class="hide" id="myIframe"></iframe>
  <form method="post" action="post.aspx" target="myIFrame"> 
     <input type="hidden" name="s_referer_email" value="test@test.com" />
     <input type="text" size="30" maxlength="255" name="s_referee_email" value="" required  >
     <input type="text" size="22" maxlength="50" name="s_referee_fname" value="" required  >
  </form>
  <form method="post" action="post.aspx" target="myIFrame">
     <input type="hidden" name="s_referer_email" value="test@test.com" />
     <input type="text" size="30" maxlength="255" name="s_referee_email" value="" >
     <input type="text" size="22" maxlength="50" name="s_referee_fname" value="" >
  </form>
  <label for="s_referer_fname">Your name:</label> <br /> <input type="text" name="s_referer_fname" value="" size="20" id="s_refererFname" ><br> 
  <p><button onclick="mySubmit();">Submit</button> </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but you're doing nothing in your code to set anything required. Could you at least share what you've tried. 

Also why multiple forms, there is no other way?

Comment: Try this `<input type="text" size="30" maxlength="255" name="s_referee_email" value=""  required>`

Comment: HI! Thanks for takign the time.  I have tried adding the html5 required attribute hoping it would be a easy fix but it seems to get ignored.

Comment: added the HTML5 required attribute to original post. it does not work

Comment: It seems like it it ignored, because that submit button only listens and submits the last form - If you move the submit button up in the first form, the "required" works fine

Answer (score 0):

Adding required="required" to the tags can let you make any field compulsory to be filled by user.

Comment: Unfortunate for some reason this attribute doesn't work.

Comment: Give me the link. I need to check there.

Comment: Why are you using several forms for something that's just one form?

Comment: It seems like it it ignored, because that submit button only listens and submits the last form - I has nothing to do with the first form

Comment: any way to force the validation to run?

Answer (score 0):

You should never use **.onclick()**, or similar attributes from a userscript.

Userscripts operate in a sandbox, and onclick operates in the target-page scope and cannot see any functions your script creates.

Always use *addEventListener()* (or an equivalent library function, like jQuery .on()).

So instead of code like:

```
something.outerHTML += '<input onclick="func()" id="button_id" ...>'
```

You would use:

```
something.outerHTML += '<input id="button_id" ...>'

document.getElementById ("button_id").addEventListener ("click", func, false);
```

And for your answer, one method is to perform a check before actually submitting the forms. Check if the required fields have been filled, if yes, go ahead and submit the form, or else don't submit and show an error message instead.